# Fever and severe headache without inflammation markers

Tags: headache, fever

What mechanisms can create fever and severe headaches lasting for a week and NOT be accompanied by any indication of inflammation in blood tests?

What diagnostic tests would be used to make a diagnosis, apart from a CT of the head and lumbar puncture?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalScience.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta]. I have voted to close this question and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: In essence, although you provide a lot of information, you are still asking for a diagnosis (why could the patient have fevere). [We had this debate before with similar posts and decided to close them.](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/958/8212)

Comment: I edited the question to remove patient-specific information and make it a generalized question that fits site guidelines.

Comment: Should the question read as fever and severe headache are the only symptoms?  Did the previous version of the question mentioned any "inflammation symptoms?" Also, the question is very broad, because causes can be very diverse and many of them can be easily excluded by knowing the circumstances.

Comment: @Jan You can see what edits were made and what previous versions said by clicking the "edited ___ hours ago" link.

Comment: OK, the OP should still explain if fever and headache are only symptoms and if blood tests have shown no indicators of inflammation, such as a high WBC. The wording "fever and headache without inflammation symptoms" is unclear, because fever itself can be a symptom of inflammation. Also, which body part was checked by a CT scan?

Comment: As Jan has said, there is a lot of missing information. As such, I've closed this as "unclear" until that information can be provided (Without turning it back into a "diagnose me" kind of question).

Comment: The differential for fever and a headache is an important one, but right now the question doesn't make a lot of sense. Fever *is* inflammatory, by definition. Hyperthermia can occur without inflammation, and fever can occur without infection, but fever can't occur without IL-1.

Comment: From the little time I've spent here I've seen users with high rep trying to force users to use this site as they see fit, and not how users want to. I strongly suggest reconsidering this strategy if you want this site to work.

Answer (score 2):

Examples of conditions with fever and severe headache in which *inflammation is not involved or is not the main process:*

- Caffeine overdose ([BMJ](http://casereports.bmj.com/content/2018/bcr-2018-224185.full))
- "Thyroid storm" - acute hyperthyropidism ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5387892/))
- Hyperparathyroidism, for example, due to adenoma of parathyroid glands ([Annals.org](http://annals.org/aim/article-abstract/693417/primary-hyperparathyroidism-presenting-fever-unknown-origin-unremitting-headache))
- Cancers and tumors, such as lymphoma, brain tumors, pituitary adenoma ([Cancer.net](https://www.cancer.net/navigating-cancer-care/side-effects/headaches))

Examples of *inflammatory* conditions with fever and severe headache:

- Temporal arteritis ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/arthritis/polymyalgia-rheumatica-temporal-arteritis#1))
- Systemic lupus erythematosus or SLE ([WebMD](https://resources.lupus.org/entry/nervous-system))
- Infectious mononucleosis ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/symptoms-of-mononucleosis))

Apart from a CT and lumbar puncture, diagnostic tests can include blood tests for thyroxine and parathyroid hormone levels, blood and other tests for the mentioned cancers and blood tests for vasculitis (arteritis).